# How can I modify the select html tag in woocommerce varistions products?

Tags: javascript, php, woocommerce

I did a JavaScript to calculate the item's price in 12 months but the problem it's I need to add a Eventlistener onblur to start the script each time that choose an item, i'm looking the PHP file and where I have to modify the cod:

```
<select id="modelos" class="" name="attribute_modelos" data-attribute_name="attribute_modelos" "="" data-show_option_none="yes"><option value="">Elige una opción</option></select>
```

I need to add the onblur="calcfin()" to load the calcfin funtion that I made, something like:

Elige una opción

or another way by JS or JQuery to get it.

Comment: Perhaps you can post some code? It is difficult for anyone to help without seeing any code to look at

Comment: of course! sorry I posted yesterday from my mobile phone... I will edit it right now